# How do I type string in the tooltip in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I would like to add the "%" symbol to the results data of the tooltip. How do we customize it?

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['@lang('home/main.korea')', '@lang('home/main.japan')'],
            datasets: [{
                label: [

                ],
                data: [
                    {!! $koreaPercent !!} ,
                    {!! $japanPercent !!} ,
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'red',
                    'blue',
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
        }
    });

</script>
```

I think we need to transform the options in the data array.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work properly:

Create a canvas for your chart:

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

This is the required javascript code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Yellow", "Red", "Black"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
      ],
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7]
    }]
  },
  options: {
      tooltips : {

      callbacks : { 
        label : function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                  return  dataset.data[tooltipItem.index] + ' %';
                },
        },
      },
  }
});
```

And this is the [Charts.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0-rc.1/Chart.js) cdn that i have used.

Here is the result:

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/3KszJQY]

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/mateusjunges/akhruj5v/9/) is a working js fiddle.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```js
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['@lang('home/main.korea')', '@lang('home/main.japan')'],
            datasets: [{
                label: [

                ],
                data: [
                    {!! $koreaPercent !!} ,
                    {!! $japanPercent !!} ,
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'red',
                    'blue',
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                        return tooltipItems.yLabel + tooltipItems.xLabel + " %";
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

here is a working example with different data, since i don't know how are u using your chart: https://jsfiddle.net/mateusjunges/f8x394va/2/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'd like to add "%" to both japan and Korea, but now it's only applied to one price.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your chart?

Comment: The tooltip has no value at this time, only "%" is displayed.

Comment: Take a look at the answer again. I've added a working example on js fiddle.

Comment: I don't know why the two graphs produce the same result.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? So i can understand whats going on.

Comment: I added a screen shot.